# sql incorrect date output incorrect

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime, where-clause

i have a table like this

```
|id|  date        |name|
 1    23/11/20    jake
 2    01/07/20    jhon
 3    23/05/20    blake
 4    11/02/20    drake
 5    1/03/14     crake
```

i ran a query like this

```
WHERE date >= '1/07/20' AND date <= '23/11/20'
```

i expected a result where i would get only the results between those dates
but i got some results which were from 2014

the data type for the date column is varchar
#note i can not change the datatype

how can i only get dates between the two ?

Comment: It's going to be really difficult. If you're storing dates, they should be in the proper data type rather than VARCHAR to prevent this exact sort of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String-wise comparison is the problem: typically, `'10/01/19'` (Janurary 10th, 2019) is greater than `'01/01/20'` (January 1st, 2020), because the former starts with `1`, and the later with `0`.

You need to turn these strings to dates before you can compare them:

```
where str_to_date(date, '%d/%m/%y') between '2020-07-01' and '2020-66-23'
```

This *is* inefficient, because the entire column needs to be converted before the filtering can happen. I would warmly recommend fixing your data model, and store dates as `date`s.

Side note: your strings need to be *consistently* formatted as `mm/dd/yy` for this to work; if you have varying formats - or strings that do not map to valid dates - then you have a bigger problem than what you have asked here.

Comment: thank u for this answer nd i understand what u mean the developer before me had it as varchar nd there r so many records like 100s of thousands of them i would need to download them and write a script to convert them
but this works for now